# Stream.publish does not work for non-admin users in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Stream.publish is working fine in face book when you are the admin of the application, but is not working for normal users.

Are there any settings that I have to change?

Comment: Define normal user. Do you mean your test users? They should have permission if they granted stream publish permissions.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on where the current users are supposed to post.
Steam.publish should work fine if the current user use that for publishing to his own profile page (if you are referring to the fb stream dialog).

and if you want to publish the post programmatically, u nee the publish_steam perm